# Two divs scrolling independently

Tags: html, css, scroll

I need help to make these two `<div>`'s  (`#side-nav` and `#content-wrapper`) to scroll independently,

## HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="top-nav">
        Top nav
    </div>
    <div id="side-nav">
        <ul>
            <li>Thing</li>
            <li>Thing</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="content-wrapper">
        <!-- Ton of conent here -->
    </div>
</div>
```

## CSS:

```
#wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #fff;
}

#top-nav {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  height: 60px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: green;
}

#side-nav {
  position: fixed;
  width: 250px;
  height:100vh;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  background-color: red;
}

#content-wrapper {
  margin: 60px 0 0 250px;
  padding: 0 30px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

now if I scroll the `#side-nav` to the end or top, `#content-wrapper` will scroll too. `#side-nav` has to stay full-page height and fixed even if there is not that many `<li>`'s.

I've quickly made pen here:

http://codepen.io/blizqery/pen/QbZzRN

Thanks!

Comment: Thats because ```content-wrapper``` doesn't scroll; it's the body that's scrolling. You need to set a height for ```content-wrapper``` that is less than its contents height to be able to use ```overflow-y```.

Comment: Problem comes from the fact that your content-wrapper is NOT scrolling. This is the whole page that's scrolling... (nav's container!) To solve that, just add a fixed height to your content-wrapper (as your side-nav)... !

Comment: add `height:100vh;` to your `#content-wrapper`. Just did it and it worked

Comment: The problem appreas because you told it to put a scrolling bar but not from what point

Comment: you have just problem with the height of the content-wraper's div

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Check this: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xGyMjM

You need to set height to content-wrapper, and also set the left, right & top.

```
#side-nav {
  position: fixed;
  width: 250px;
  height:100vh;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  background-color: red;
  top: 60px;
}

#content-wrapper {
  margin: 60px 0 0 250px;
  padding: 0 30px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height:100vh;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

Comment: This works well, but now it doesnt show all content and menu <li>'s. It hides them at the very bottom.

Comment: Yes, it is the issue because of px & vh - they are not syncing together well. That issue also exists in our original CodePen. you need to set the viewport height in pixels by calculating the height of the viewport - 60 (top nag height) => the same height for both (side-nav & content). Let me know if you need help with that, I can create a CodePen

Comment: I just replaced all height:100hv; with height: calc(100% - 60px); and it works well thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this works for your issue

```
   body{
      margin:0px;
    }
    #top-nav {
      position: fixed;
      top: 0;
      height: 10vh;
      width: 100%;
      background-color: green;
    }
    #wrapper {
      width: 100%;
      background-color: #fff;
    }

    #side-nav {
      float:left;
      width: 250px;
      height: 90vh;
      overflow-y: scroll;
      background-color: red;
    }

    #content-wrapper {
      margin: 10vh 0 0 250px;
      padding: 0 30px;
      overflow-y: scroll;
      background-color: blue;
      height:90vh;
    }
```