# Scroll two bootstrap cols independently

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have two `bootstrap 4` cards on a page that contain content of differing length.

I want to set the initial height of the cards to extend to the bottom of the page, and `overflow-y: scroll` on each card independently.

See below for my code ([same thing as a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0yopng1j/5/)).

Currently, scrolling on one card causes the other to scroll too. How can I get them to scroll independently? The answer to [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31647945/two-divs-scrolling-independently) suggests setting the height of the parent div, which I am currently doing (`#message-row{height: 100%}`), so I can't see what I'm doing wrong.

I would also like to make sure that the footer for the right had card is always at the bottom of the **visible** card (i.e. so that you don't have to scroll to the bottom of the card to see it.

```css
.message-card {
  font-weight: 400;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
.inbox-card {
  font-weight: 300;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
#message-row {
  height: 500px;
  color: #232323;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  text-align: left;
}
#message-row .card {
  border-radius: 5px;
}
#message-row input {
  width: 70%;
  color: #0e5286 !important;
}
#message-row input.form-control {
  height: unset !important;
  background: #f5f9fc;
}
#message-row .inbox-row {
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-left: 0;
  padding-bottom: 1em;
}
#message-row .inbox-row:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #f5f9fc;
}
.speech-bubble {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 100%;
  min-height: 40px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 0.5em;
}
.speech-bubble.them {
  background: rgba(155, 194, 214, 0.6);
}
.speech-bubble.me {
  background: rgba(156, 199, 160, 0.6);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-UHRtZLI+pbxtHCWp1t77Bi1L4ZtiqrqD80Kn4Z8NTSRyMA2Fd33n5dQ8lWUE00s/" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="container d-flex h-100 flex-column">

  <div id="message-row" class="row mb-4">
    <div class="col-lg-5 pb-md-4 pb-lg-0">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="searchBar">
          <input id="inbox-search" class="form-control mx-auto mt-2" type="text" placeholder="Search..." />
        </div>
        <div id="inbox" class="card-body">
          <div class="row inbox-row">
            <div class='col-12'>
              <p>Some content 1 </p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row inbox-row">
            <div class='col-12'>
              <p>Some more content</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row inbox-row">
            <div class='col-12'>
              <p>Some content again </p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row inbox-row">
            <div class='col-12'>
              <p>Some content asdaa</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row inbox-row">
            <div class='col-12'>
              <p>Some asdacc </p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row inbox-row">
            <div class='col-12'>
              <p>Some contention</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row inbox-row">
            <div class='col-12'>
              <p>Some contention</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row inbox-row">
            <div class='col-12'>
              <p>Some contention</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row inbox-row">
            <div class='col-12'>
              <p>Some contention</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-7">
      <div class="card message-card">
        <div id="conversation" class="card-body">
          <div class='row'>
            <div class='col-8 float-right'>
              <div class='speech-bubble me'>A message</div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class='row'>
            <div class='col-8 float-right'>
              <div class='speech-bubble me'>Another message</div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class='row'>
            <div class='col-8 float-right'>
              <div class='speech-bubble them'>A reply</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      <div id="new-message" class="card-footer">
        <form id="reply-form" method="POST">
          <input type="hidden" name="sender" value="<abcd">
          <div class="form-info-text form-group mb-0">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-11">
                <textarea class="form-control autoExpand" rows="1" name="message"></textarea>
              </div>
              <div class="col-1 send-col">
                <button type="submit" disabled><i id="sendMessage" class="far fa-paper-plane"></i></button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class='container-fluid'>
<div class='row'>
<div class='col-12'>
<h1>
Some other container that expands full width...
</h1>
</div>
</div>

</div>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove height and overflow from class message-row also reduce height in message-card and include a class inbox in first card

```
 .inbox {
  font-weight: 300;
  height: 80%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```css
.message-card {
  font-weight: 400;
  height: 80%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
.inbox {
  font-weight: 300;
  height: 80%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
#message-row {
  color: #232323;
  text-align: left;
}
#message-row .card {
  border-radius: 5px;
}
#message-row input {
  width: 70%;
  color: #0e5286 !important;
}
#message-row input.form-control {
  height: unset !important;
  background: #f5f9fc;
}
#message-row .inbox-row {
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-left: 0;
  padding-bottom: 1em;
}
#message-row .inbox-row:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #f5f9fc;
}
.speech-bubble {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 100%;
  min-height: 40px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 0.5em;
}
.speech-bubble.them {
  background: rgba(155, 194, 214, 0.6);
}
.speech-bubble.me {
  background: rgba(156, 199, 160, 0.6);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-UHRtZLI+pbxtHCWp1t77Bi1L4ZtiqrqD80Kn4Z8NTSRyMA2Fd33n5dQ8lWUE00s/" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="container d-flex h-100 flex-column">

  <div id="message-row" class="row mb-4">
    <div class="col-lg-5 pb-md-4 pb-lg-0">
      <div class="card inbox">
        <div class="searchBar">
          <input id="inbox-search" class="form-control mx-auto mt-2" type="text" placeholder="Search..." />
        </div>
        <div id="inbox" class="card-body ">
          <div class="row inbox-row">
            <div class='col-12'>
              <p>Some content 1 </p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row inbox-row">
            <div class='col-12'>
              <p>Some more content</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row inbox-row">
            <div class='col-12'>
              <p>Some content again </p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row inbox-row">
            <div class='col-12'>
              <p>Some content asdaa</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row inbox-row">
            <div class='col-12'>
              <p>Some asdacc </p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row inbox-row">
            <div class='col-12'>
              <p>Some contention</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row inbox-row">
            <div class='col-12'>
              <p>Some contention</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row inbox-row">
            <div class='col-12'>
              <p>Some contention</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row inbox-row">
            <div class='col-12'>
              <p>Some contention</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-7">
      <div class="card message-card">
        <div id="conversation" class="card-body">
          <div class='row'>
            <div class='col-8 float-right'>
              <div class='speech-bubble me'>A message</div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class='row'>
            <div class='col-8 float-right'>
              <div class='speech-bubble me'>Another message</div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class='row'>
            <div class='col-8 float-right'>
              <div class='speech-bubble them'>A reply</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div id="new-message" class="card-footer">
          <form id="reply-form" method="POST">
            <input type="hidden" name="sender" value="<abcd">
            <div class="form-info-text form-group mb-0">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-11">
                  <textarea class="form-control autoExpand" rows="1" name="message"></textarea>
                </div>
                <div class="col-1 send-col">
                  <button type="submit" disabled><i id="sendMessage" class="far fa-paper-plane"></i></button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class='container-fluid'>
    <div class='row'>
      <div class='col-12'>
        <h1>
          Some other container that expands full width...
        </h1>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually after banging my head against the desk for several hours I realised that the solution was simple: It's the `col`s that need `overflow-y: scroll`, not the cards. Thus adding class `scroll-col` to each column fixes the problem:

```
.scroll-col{
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

([See fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0yopng1j/6/))